# Python or C for network measurement tool

Tags: python, c, sockets, networking, network-programming

I am planning to create a network measurement tool in 3G networks. I am just thinking in which language I should code- C or Python. Personally I love python, but i also feel that it is a bit slow and since i need to record the timestamps of packet sent and received and i need them to be as precise as possible(as soon as server has some packet to send, it should send and as soon as receiver receives a packet,the application should note the time stamp) , should I use Python or use C?

Comment: Yes, you should use Python or C.

Comment: among python and C, which one?

Comment: Why do you need to only use _one_ of them?

Comment: because i know network programming only in these two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your time is the most valuable, so code in whatever language you feel most comfortable. Python is slower than C in most cases, but on modern hardware it is still very fast. If you go the Python route, write your program, then use a [profiler](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html) to figure out if you have a particular section slowing you down. If you can streamline it enough to meet your timing needs, great. If not, you can always write a function or class in C and link it in using [swig](http://www.swig.org/).

> We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. --Donald Knuth